# Using empty string ("") as name for ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wonder why it seems a problem using empty strings for `ng-app`.
In the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_controller) provided by w3school, I attempted using empty string to name the ng-app as below, but failed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
    </script>
<body>

<p>Try to change the names.</p>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
    Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.firstName= "John";
      $scope.lastName= "Doe";
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Even making a `" "` will make the ng-app directive work. Any ideas?

The reason I was wondering this question is that I learned one example realizing same functionalities without initializing a controller and the ng-app is an empty string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John'">

<p>The name is <span ng-bind="firstName"></span></p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @sma I made an edit adding another example. This made me think why we can't make that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set a name to your module, or otherwise not use a module and delete the 'ng-app' from you html.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I edited the question and added another example without instantiation of a controller and this time the ng-app is "". I realize this is really the reason I thought about the question. I would like to know the reason why we can do it in my second example.

Comment: my fault! you don`t have to delete the ng-app directive if you dont have a module.
"The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. " [link to ngApp documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) .

thats why you second example works without a reference to a module.

Comment: So if there is no need of further defining module, we can simply leave the ng-app name as `""`?

Comment: yes, you can leave the ng-app directive as : ng-app="" or just ng-app

Answer (score 1):

An empty string null.

But a spaced string is still a string.

Thats why you can use it.

Comment: A *spaced string* actually makes it work, as the OP explained.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I edited the question and added another example without instantiation of a controller and this time the ng-app is `""`. I realize this is really the reason I thought about the question. I would like to know the reason why we can do it in my second example.