# Meaning of the empty array in angularJS module declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module, angularjs-module

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923949/using-empty-string-as-name-for-ng-app), I understand that the code `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);` connects the module `app` to the view `myApp`.

I would like to know why we are having the empty array `[]` in the module declaration.

What is the empty array used for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> That array is meant to add various module to your current `app` which
>   is mentioned in your first part of `angular.module` as string`, You could simply
>   say for injecting various dependency.

You could create an `n` number of module inside your app for each component of `angular` & then you could combine them into one single app and you can `angular.bootstrap` or apply it on page using `ng-app` directive.

**Example**

Suppose you have an app which has different component like services, factory, filters, directives, etc. You could create a module for each of them. Just for making separation of concern.

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
angular.module('myApp.constants', [])
```

And while appending an component to it you could simply use that specific module of it. Like you wanted to add service then you just add that service into `myApp.services` by doing

```
angular.module('myApp.services').service('example', function(){

})
```

And then inside you app.js you could do combine all of this modules to an single module like below.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
     'myApp.services', 
     'myApp.controllers', 
     'myApp.directives', 
     'myApp.directives', 
     'myApp.constants'
])
```

While initializing an app you could simply use `myApp` inside, that would make available all other module to it.

> What is the empty array used for?

In you code you are creating an module which doesn't inject any dependency, `[]` which means it is independent of any other `angular` module.

> Dependency injected inside the `[]` is nothing but importing module

Answer (score 21):

`angular.module('app', [])` is to create a new module without any module dependency.

`angular.module('app')` is to retrieve an existing module whose name is `app`.

Comment: Not more or less needed, this is the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Angulars API says `Passing one argument retrieves an existing angular.Module, whereas passing more than one argument creates a new angular.Module`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module