# Angular route issue with attached controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am using angular route for my project. My project structure like below.

> index page

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-view></div>


   <script src="resources/js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="resources/angular/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="resources/js/route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="resources/js/quotation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="resources/js/container_details.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   <script src="resources/angular/angular-modal-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/containers/resources/js/user-registration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </body>
```

my route.js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngTable','jcs-autoValidate','ngRoute']);

    // configure our routes
    app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider
        .when('/containers', {
            templateUrl : 'template.jsp'


        })
            .when('/container-details', {
                templateUrl : 'container-details.jsp',
                controller  : 'myCtrl'

            })
            .when('/quotation-approve', {
                templateUrl : 'quotation_approve.jsp',
                controller  : 'ourCtrl'

            })
                .when('/user-registration', {
                templateUrl : 'user-registration.jsp',
                controller  : 'userCtrl'

            })


        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

/*  app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {  
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);*/
```

I defined all modules as below:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
```

when i load page error occur. error said 
[image]

> user registration.js

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp");

app.run(function(defaultErrorMessageResolver, validator) {
  validator.setValidElementStyling(false);
  defaultErrorMessageResolver.getErrorMessages().then(function(errorMessages) {
    errorMessages['min-length'] = 'Username must be at least {0} letters';
    errorMessages['max-length'] = 'Username must be  {0} letters Only';
    errorMessages['pwError'] = "Password should be atleast 8 characters long and should contain one number,one character and one special character";
    errorMessages['passwordVerify'] = "password not matched";
    errorMessages['validEmail'] = "Please enter a valid email address";
  });

});


app.controller('userCtrl', function($scope, $http, NgTableParams, $timeout, $filter) {

  $scope.getAllUserDetails = function() {
    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/containers/getUserRolle"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.getAllRolesDetails();
      $scope.userRolless = response.data.userRolles;
      //        console.log( $scope.userRolless);
      $scope.getDatas();
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.userRolless = response.data.userRolles;
    });
  }


  $scope.getAllTableData = function() {
    // $scope.edituserdetails={};
    //$scope.edituserdetails.activeuser=true;
    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/containers/getUserRolle"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      //        $scope.getAllRolesDetails();
      $scope.userRolless = response.data.userRolles;
      //          console.log( $scope.userRolless);
      $scope.getDatas();
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.userRolless = response.data.userRolles;
    });
  }

  $scope.getDatas = function() {
    console.log("tesssst" + $scope.userRolless);
    //console.log("tesssst"+$scope.userRolless.object.name);
    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
      page: 1, // show first page
      count: 5,
      // count per page
      // filter: {name: '' },
      // sorting: { username: "asc" },

    }, {
      dataset: $scope.userRolless
    });

  }






  $scope.getAllRolesDetailsById = function(roleId) {

    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/containers/getUserRoleById",
      params: {
        roleId: roleId
      }
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      console.log(response.data.userAllRollesById);
      $scope.userAllRolles = response.data.userAllRollesById;
      $scope.edituserdetails.role = $scope.userAllRolles[0];

      // console.log("user Active status"+ $scope.edituserdetails.activeuser);
    }, function myError(response) {
      console.log(response.data.userAllRolles);
      $scope.userAllRolles = response.data.userAllRollesById;
    });

  }

  $scope.editUserFunction = function(usersid) {

    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/containers/getUserDetails",
      params: {
        userId: usersid
      }
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.edituserdetails = response.data.userDetails;
      $scope.username = response.data.userDetails.username;
      $scope.getAllRolesDetailsById($scope.edituserdetails.roleId);
      console.log(response.data.userDetails);

      console.log("user Active status" + response.data.userDetails.userstatus);
      if (response.data.userDetails.userstatus === 'Y') {
        $scope.edituserdetails.activeuser = true;
      } else {
        $scope.edituserdetails.activeuser = false;
      }
      $scope.edituserdetails.password = "";
      $scope.edituserdetails.confirmpassword = "";
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.edituserdetails = response.data.userRolles;
    });

    //     console.log(usersid);
  }


  $scope.getExistingUserValidateFunction = function(userName) {

    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/containers/validateUser",
      params: {
        userName: userName
      }
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      var test = response.data.ExistingUserStatus
      console.log("ddddd" + test);
      return test;

    }, function myError(response) {
      //       return response.data.ExistingUserStatus;
    });

  }


  $scope.changePassword = function() {
    console.log("ddddd" + $scope.edituserdetails.activeuser);
    if ($scope.edituserdetails.activeuser) {
      activeuserstatus = 'Y';
    } else {
      activeuserstatus = 'N';
    }
    console.log("ccccc" + activeuserstatus);
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/containers/registrationuser",
        data: {
          "email": $scope.edituserdetails.email,
          "username": $scope.username,
          "password": $scope.edituserdetails.password,
          "id": $scope.edituserdetails.id,
          "role": $scope.edituserdetails.role,
          "userstatus": activeuserstatus


        }

      })
      .success(function(data) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.msgType = false;
        }, 3000);
        $scope.theform.$setPristine();
        if (data.errorList.length > 0) {
          $scope.fieldErrorList = data.errorList;
          $scope.msgType = 'Error';
        } else {
          $scope.msgType = 'Success';
          $scope.getAllTableData();
        }

        $scope.theform.$setPristine();
        //     document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;



        //                $scope.resetFunction();

      });



    // Posting data to php file
  }

  /* form.$setPristine = function() {
     $animate.setClass(element, PRISTINE_CLASS, DIRTY_CLASS + ' ' + SUBMITTED_CLASS);
     form.$dirty = false;
     form.$pristine = true;
     form.$submitted = false;
     forEach(controls, function(control) {
       control.$setPristine();
     });
   };*/

  $scope.saveUserFunction = function() {
    console.log("ddddd" + $scope.edituserdetails.activeuser);
    if ($scope.edituserdetails.activeuser) {
      activeuserstatus = 'Y';
    } else {
      activeuserstatus = 'N';
    }
    console.log("ccccc" + activeuserstatus);
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/containers/registrationuser",
        data: {
          "email": $scope.edituserdetails.email,
          "username": $scope.username,
          "password": $scope.edituserdetails.password,
          "id": $scope.edituserdetails.id,
          "role": $scope.edituserdetails.role,
          "userstatus": activeuserstatus


        }

      })
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log($scope.theform);
        if (data.errorList.length > 0) {
          $scope.fieldErrorList = data.errorList;
          $scope.msgType = 'Error';
          $scope.theform.$setPristine();
        } else {
          $scope.msgType = 'Success';
          // $scope.edituserdetails = {};
          $scope.resetFunction();
          $scope.getAllTableData();
          $timeout(function() {
            $scope.msgType = false;
          }, 3000);
          $scope.theform.$setPristine();
        }


        //     document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;



        $scope.resetFunction();
        $scope.theform.$setPristine();
      });



    // Posting data to php file
  }


  $scope.resetFunction = function() {
    $scope.edituserdetails = {};
    $scope.username = '';
    $scope.edituserdetails.role = $scope.userAllRolles[0];
    $scope.theform.$setPristine();
  }

  $scope.checkPwd = function() {

    var str = document.getElementById('pw').value;
    if (str.length < 6) {
      alert("too_short");
      return ("too_short");
    } else if (str.length > 50) {
      alert("too_long");
      return ("too_long");
    } else if (str.search(/\d/) == -1) {
      alert("no_num");
      return ("no_num");
    } else if (str.search(/[a-zA-Z]/) == -1) {
      alert("no_letter");
      return ("no_letter");
    } else if (str.search(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/) != -1) {
      alert("bad_char");
      return ("bad_char");
    }
    alert("oukey!!");
    return ("ok");
  }


  $scope.changePasswordFucntion = function(username) {
    console.log(username);

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/containers/changePassword",
        data: {
          "password": $scope.edituserdetails.password,
          "username": username,
          "curruntPassword": $scope.edituserdetails.curruntpassword,
          "passwordConfirm": $scope.edituserdetails.confirmpassword

        }

      })
      .success(function(data) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.msgType = false;
        }, 3000);
        $scope.theform.$setPristine();
        if (data.errorList.length > 0) {
          $scope.fieldErrorList = data.errorList;
          $scope.msgType = 'Error';
        } else {
          $scope.msgType = 'Success';
          $scope.getAllTableData();
        }

        $scope.theform.$setPristine();


      });
  }

  $scope.getAllRolesDetails = function() {

    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/containers/getUserAlRolles"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      //  console.log(response.data.userAllRolles);
      $scope.userAllRolles = response.data.userAllRolles;
      $scope.edituserdetails = response.data.userAllRolles;
      $scope.edituserdetails.role = response.data.userAllRolles[0];

    }, function myError(response) {
      // console.log(response.data.userAllRolles);
      $scope.userAllRolles = response.data.userAllRolles;
    });

  }




})
app.directive("passwordVerify", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
      passwordVerify: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, myCtrl) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
        var combined;

        if (scope.passwordVerify || myCtrl.$viewValue) {
          combined = scope.passwordVerify + '_' + myCtrl.$viewValue;
        }
        return combined;
      }, function(value) {
        if (value) {
          myCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
            var origin = scope.passwordVerify;
            if (origin !== viewValue) {
              myCtrl.$setValidity("passwordVerify", false);
              return undefined;
            } else {
              myCtrl.$setValidity("passwordVerify", true);
              return viewValue;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please show the code for `user-registration.js`

Comment: i edited. pls check dear Rahul

Comment: can you try having different module like `var app = angular.module("userRegistration");` in user-registration.js and in route.js `var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngTable','jcs-autoValidate','ngRoute','userRegistration']);`

Comment: then how i define 'ng-app' in my index page?

Comment: you already have `myApp` in route.js file so in index.html you can use `ng-app="myApp"`

Comment: its not working

Comment: Place the `angular.js` and the `angular-route` inside the `<head>` tag? To make sure its loaded before the `HTML` is rendered?

Comment: @user1177842can you  try `var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);` in user-registration.js ?
just add empty dependency array.

Comment: I agree with @RahulNaik comment.

Comment: Hi Rahul i added empty dependency array. Now another error comes
Error  - 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: defaultErrorMessageResolverProvider <- defaultErrorMessageResolver

Comment: this is all together different issue. Looks like you haven't included defaultErrorMessageResolver module

Comment: @user1177842. it may be wrong injection. You should check the providers and where it will inject.. I think `'jcs-autoValidate'` should inject in your `registration.js` instead of `route.js`. and **kindly check you have referred the script in your index page**

Answer (score 0):

`var app = angular.module("myApp");`

This above code does not create module called `myApp` it just referring an existing module. If you have not yet created the module, then the error will threw which is you have mentioned.

To create the module do this.

`angular.module('myApp', []);`

---

Please read this below discussion to more details:

[Meaning of the empty array in angularJS module declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924967/meaning-of-the-empty-array-in-angularjs-module-declaration)

Comment: Dear Ramesh, i injected all things in route.js. other js files keep like below 
var app = angular.module("myApp");

Comment: Ramesh, Not Rumesh :) . But did you refer the related script file in your index page?

Comment: all js files attached in index file

Comment: i changed dependency injecting as below 

Rout .js
var app = angular.module('myApp');

user-registration.js
var app = angular.module("myApp",['ngTable','jcs-autoValidate','ngRoute']);

now no errors. but page not loaded.