# What is the meaning of components inside array when declaring angular js module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

I am new in angular js. I have the following code

```
angular.module('app', ['components'])

.controller('MyApp', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello World!";
});
```

what is the meaning of `components` here ?

I tried to find something on angular js documentation `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module`

but there when they declare a new module the array is empty, in my case the array is not empty - so what does it means ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of the empty array in angularJS module declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924967/meaning-of-the-empty-array-in-angularjs-module-declaration)

Comment: @SudhirOjha no because my question is what is the meaning if something is putted into the array !